# Moving From {{ mustache }} To Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mustache, client-side-templating, templating-engine

we were loading template from external file into layout using mustache which is ok but also we had to make each template stand alone, with style and JS and html in same file, which isn't possible with mustache and we moved to VueJs with single file component.

Is it good choice to use Vue for this scenario or there some light weight JS template engine we are missing ?

https://github.com/furqanfreed/MustacheJs-to-VueJs

Comment: hi @Furqan, your question looks like primary based opinion. Yes VueJS can do the job, as any other major framework such as Angular, ReactJs and PreactJS.

Comment: Thank you @Yanis-git agree any other major framework can do this or maybe some modern JS templating engines but i am looking for lighter one with less footprint with functionality i mentioned above.

Comment: You can have look on ReactJS or PreactJS (lighter than ReactJS and same coding style), but as i said, is primary based opinion. My critera will may : (1) Number of available library, (2) Number of available documentation, (3) Possibility for my project to grow up by the right way. Stability of 3th party library.